# facebook request parameters

Tags: facebook

Is there any chance to hand over a parameter to a facebook tab?

Comment: Maybe the two answers below don't understand your question....  Are you trying to pass data into your app from a link?  If so, the 'app_data' response below are correct.  But, if you just want a different parameter, you can add it to the Page Tab URL in the app's configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the app_data parameter of the signed_request. As far as I know, that's currently the only way to do it.

> A JSON string containing the content
>   of a query string parameter also
>   called app_data. Usually specified
>   when the application built the link to
>   pass some data to itself. Only
>   available if your app is an iframe
>   loaded in a Page tab.

source: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request

Answer (score 1):

With the `app_data`. Here's an example:

www.facebook.com/pagename?sk=app_12345678910&app_data=%7B%22item1%22%3A%22data%22%7D

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$obj = json_decode($signed_request['app_data']);
print $obj->{'item1'}; //prints data
```